# Merging two dictionaries based on content positions

Tags: javascript

I have two dictionaries that are recordings of the same event with different steps taken.

```
A: [ { tap red }, { tap blue }, { tap green }, { tap commit } ]

B: [ { tap yellow }, { tap blue }, { tap commit } ]
```

The merged should look like:

```
[ { tap yellow }, { tap red }, { tap blue }, { tap green }, { tap commit } ]
```

yellow and red and done in both A and B before blue so it should be positioned before `{ tap blue }`, `{ tap green }` is before `{ tap commit }`, and `{ tap commit }` is always at the end.

What's the best way of implementing this in JavaScript?

Comment: How should `A:[a,b]; B:[b,a]` be merged?

Comment: There is something wrong with your syntax...

Comment: I believe the dictionary items would look like `{ tap: 'red' }`.

Comment: Should we, assuming the inputs are consistent, produce a merge that is set-wise a union of the two, consistent with both, and ambiguities are resolved by moving the entries from  B before the entries from A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics depend on exactly how you want it to behave in various degenerate cases, but broadly speaking: (rough pseudo-javascript)

```
var position_B = 0
foreach( A as position_A ) {
    var found_B = B.indexOf( A[position_A], position_B );
    if( found_B !== -1 ) {
        // todo: copy B[position_B] to B[found_B] (inclusive) into Result
        position_B = found_B + 1;
    } else {
        // todo: copy A[position_A] into Result
    }
}
// todo: copy B[position_B] to B[end] (inclusive) into Result
```

It loops through all items of A, and for each one, checks if it is in B. If it is, it copies all the items between the last match and current match of B, otherwise it just copies A. Then it includes everything in B which hasn't been included so far at the end.